# On Android Turbolinks, how to create custom progressView to replace default spinner?

Tags: android, turbolinks, turbolinks-5, turbolinks-android

On Android using Turbolinks 5, I am not getting the classic Turbolinks transition (without any intervening white page and with horizontal progress bar on top). So  **I think I need my own progressView** *but I may be wrong*

I have this in my **MainActivity.java**

```
        progressView = new ProgressBar(turbolinksView.getContext());
        TurbolinksSession.getDefault(this)
                .activity(this)
                .adapter(this)
                .view(turbolinksView)
                .progressView(progressView, R.id.indeterminateBar, 300)
                .visit(location);
```

and this in my **activity_main.xml**

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

gradle settings are

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 22
```

when I run the above I get `IllegalArgumentException "A progress indicator view must be provided in your custom progressView."` so I tried

```
.progressView(progressView, progressView.getId(), 300)
```

but I still get `IllegalArgumentException "A progress indicator view must be provided in your custom progressView."`

**Obviously I am unable to instantiate the right `progressView`, my question is what how do I get/create the right `progressView` ??**

*Apologies in advance for cross posting the question from [Turbolinks-Android](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android/issues/80) the only reason I posted it here too is I have been stuck on it for days*

Answer (score 3):

I was checking Turbolinks-Android repository and I noticed that the possible cause of this exception is because your progressView object doesn't have `R.id.indeterminateBar` as a child view.

Long story short, you could try that:

on your **activity_main.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

on your **MainActivity.java**:

```
View progressView = (View) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
TurbolinksSession.getDefault(this)
     .activity(this)
     .adapter(this)
     .view(turbolinksView)
     .progressView(progressView, R.id.indeterminateBar, 300)
     .visit(location);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android/blob/master/turbolinks/src/main/java/com/basecamp/turbolinks/TurbolinksSession.java#L337). Your `progressView` should be some Layout like `FrameLayout` and it has to contain `R.id.indeterminateBar` inside. So it would be something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressView"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<FrameLayout/>
```